# What is "humanity in general"?

Tags: meaning

Couldn't find it in the dictionary. I couldn't find it even after searching.

> You can effectively channel your self-imposed obligations to your immediate environment and humanity in general by choosing an occupation that deals specifically with these matters.

Comment: Try looking up ***humanity*** and then ***in general***.